# LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

There are probably dozens of questions with duplicate titles at SO, I apologize if this is a duplicate, but my limited experience with LINQ I was not able to find a resolution. I am trying to retrieve the last message, the FirstName and lastname, and date last message was sent, grouped by identNumber. the sql query works fine, the LINQ returns:

```
Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types
```

Apparently something is null but I'm not sure what the correct translation would be.

The SQL:

```
SELECT     e.identNumber, e.DateSent, e.FirstName, e.LastName
FROM         Echo.vw_EchoChatMessages AS e,
  (SELECT MAX(DateSent) AS MaxDate, identNumber
  FROM Echo.vw_EchoChatMessages
  GROUP BY identNumber ) MaxResults
WHERE e.identNumber = MaxResults.identNumber
AND e.DateSent = MaxResults.MaxDate
```

the LINQ (closest I can get):

```
                var qry = from c in db.vw_EchoChatMessages
                      let maxDate = (from d in db.vw_EchoChatMessages select d.DateSent).Max()
                      where c.DateSent.Equals(maxDate)
                      select new { c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.DateSent };
```

Please advise as able, thanx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF does not recognize the implicit conversion from `Nullable<T>` to `object`, which the compiler generates for the `.Equals()` call.

Change that to the `==` operator and you should be fine, because the spec defines an equality operator between `T` and `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: Thank you. This was a huge help! Would have never have figured this out.